# How to organize modular web app

Tags: php, javascript

I have a web site, which has multiple modules on a typical "dashboard" page. All of them communicate with the same database, and same set of tables, some of them do the job of writing, some display, etc.

Should I use iframe to achieve that or combine all the codes or is there other options?

Those modules can interact with each other on a client-side javascript level. For example, I click a button in module A, a textbox in module B will be hidden.

Moreover, how do you achieve such that, when I use module A to write things to the database, module B will know it's time to fetch new data again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the different bits of your web page need to communicate with each other, then I don’t think iframes are a great idea. (I could be missing something though.)

You might want to have a look at [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/). It gives you a model/view framework in JavaScript, with automatic re-rendering of views when their model changes, that might make it easier for you to keep all your modules in sync with each other.

You’d basically replicate your database objects in a Backbone.js model on page load, then have your on-page modules keep in sync with their Backbone.js model, instead of repeatedly polling the server for changes that have happened right there in the page anyway.

Comment: Thank you. That gives me some directions!

Comment: @William: you’re most welcome! I’ve been trying to find something to use Backbone.js on for a while. Looks like you’ve got a great candidate.

Comment: I'm feverently reading up on Backbone.js at the moment. The application I am building is pretty sophisticated. So, framework likes this should help, though unclear how it'll work at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I use iframe to achieve that or combine all the codes or is there other options?

Better: template driven website

> Moreover, how do you achieve such that, when I use module A to write things to the database, module B will know it's time to fetch new data again.

There are a lot of ways, example:

1. Add a bool column 'flag', to mark whether a row has been changed or not (assume 1 if
   modified, 0 otherwise)
2. Module B queries the server (you're using AJAX, right?) in a given interval to check for
   those 'flag', retrieve them and set to 0, then redisplay them as necessary

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any reason to use iframes for what you've described. A Javascript UI library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) takes all the sweat out of manipulating different elements of a web page whilst keeping your markup cleaner, so you should probably check that out first.

If that still doesn't solve your problem communicating between different modules, take a look at [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/): it's a Javascript model/view/controller library that helps you decouple your model (in your case, your database code) and the views that send data to it and/or respond to its update events (your dashboard widgets).